# Voltage gain VS power gain in an oscillator

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, loop-gain

I just have a general question about amplifiers for oscillators.

Is it a necessary condition that the amplifier has to have overall power gain or just voltage gain (and decreasing the current so that the power does not change) in order for the oscillator to oscillate and recover the losses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute requirement is that it has power gain.

It then depends on the impedances presented by the circuit whether you can locate any notional voltage gain or current gain.

A circuit with a transformer in it can change impedances significantly, and so you have to be very careful that you know what impedance is being presented where before you can assert that an apparent voltage or current gain actually delivers you a power gain.

At the oscillation frequency, many circuits, for instance the L and two Cs of a Colpitts oscillator, can behave like a transformer, with the impedance across one C being very much lower than the impedance across both.

In the steady state, the energy lost in the resonant circuit losses will be exactly made up by the energy delivered from the sustaining device.

Answer (score 0):

> *It is a necessary condition that the amplifier has to have overall
> power gain or just voltage gain*

A practical sinewave oscillator will have both voltage gain (especially for starting the oscillations) and some power gain to overcome losses in feedback components. Once the oscillation amplitude has stabilized the voltage gain will be slightly over a value of 1 and by how much over 1 is dictated by the power losses in the feedback circuit and amplifier itself.

Comment: So since there is power loss in the circuit, you will always need power gain, right. But what if there is a constant supply of power to the circuit and the power stays the same because of this? Then wouldn't just voltage amplification be enough?

Comment: Power loss has to be overcome by an injection of power from the power supply and, its almost certain that the power injected will remain the same due the the dynamic behaviour inside a decent oscillator circuit. That's about as close to answering your query/comment as I could figure out.

Comment: I actually meant that the power will remain the same in the oscillator if the power from the supply remains the same, although, the power will be decreased in the oscillator, lower than the power supply because of the losses. But it will still be constant given that the losses are constant as well. So then, wouldn't just voltage gain be enough to sustain the oscillations?

Comment: The average power consumed by the oscillator and load will be the average power supplied from the power supply that's for sure. Saying it's constant only applies the average values because the instantaneous power supplied from the power supply will vary with the instantaneous value of the output waveform and, that is cyclic. Sorry I'm doing my best to give you an answer but I'm really not sure about your question here. "just voltage gain" isn't enough; you need some small amount of voltage gain and some small amount of power gain for simple oscillators that don't use a transformer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I meant average power because it is an AC system.